# Applying mathematics to design

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

I need help on this and i am also curious to know what looks better, applying mathematics or using designer eye  [image: Logo design]

I asked a graphic designer to design my company logo. The width of the logo is divided by 7 bars that should spread nicely on the logo width. How can we have the distance between each bars grow exponentially from right to left and yet fit perfectly within the width of the card and look pleasing to the eye.

At the moment something feels wrong about the logo and i think it is all about proportion

I believe some simple math should solve this but i don't know how to apply it

At the end i need to tell the designer what distance each segment is.

I came up with this

X = total width of the logo

A=first segment width    ( the first segment width should be between 1/15th to 1/10 of the logo width, to me it looks alright but feel free to come up with your own ratio)

B=second segment width
C= third segment width

Each segment is growing exponentially from right to left.

A=x/10
B=AxZ
C=BxZ
D=CxZ
E=DxZ
F=ExZ
G=FxZ
......

Z=growth multplier ?

A+B+C+D+E+F+G = X

What is Z ?

What is A ?

Answer (score 2):

So imagine the upper part of the logo is, say, 128 units long. I chose this because $2^7 = 128$. Let the lower, right-most point of the black triangle be the point $A$. Halfway across the top (which is 128/2 = 64 units from the top-left corner), connect a line from there to $A$. Next, move to the right 64/2 = 32 units and connect this point to $A$ also. Continue in this fashion (16, 8, 4, 2, 1) units away from the top-left corner, each time connecting with a line weight you fell appropriate, and Voila! You now have 7 bars creating 7 intervals, each interval having double the length of the one to its right. Of course, you would have to scale 128 units to be the length of the top of the card so that way you can solve for the length of your smallest unit (1 unit).

I'm trying to illustrate my idea so I will edit this answer soon with an image. When I think exponential growth, an easy way to do this "by hand" is with powers of 2. That is, doubling or halving a segment each time.

Another way I'm thinking about is using Fibonacci numbers to create a scaled spacing along the top part of the logo. I'll see if I can illustrate this one too!

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the sum of a geometric series (one that increases exponentially) is $$a\frac{(r^n-1)}{r-1},$$ where your initial value is $a$, number of terms is $n$, and your growth rate is $r$. So you can set the expression equal to the width of your card, and set $n=8$ (because you have 8 spaces), and then mess around with your $a$ and $r$ values until you find something you like.